# How do I properly send a POST in HTTPS through Java?

Tags: java, https

I'm writing a mod for a game in Java to check to see if the player has voted using a server methods to get the Steam ID. I can't get a good response from what I'm seeing. Every response is an IOException which I've had print out "Invalid Response Code".

I've tried implementing what I've seen in similar mods for https connections, but I am not getting anywhere with it.

```java
try {
  HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(             "https://somewebsite.com/"
                ).openConnection();
                connection.setSSLSocketFactory(createTrustAllSocketFactory());

                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode != 200) throw new IOException("Invalid response code.");

                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

                ByteArrayOutputStream stringBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                int len = 0;
                while (len != -1) {
                    stringBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    len = in.read(buffer);
                }

                String result = new String(stringBuffer.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                if (result.equals("1")) {
                    try {
                        performer.addMoney(MonetaryConstants.COIN_COPPER * 5);
                        performer.getCommunicator().sendNormalServerMessage("Thanks for voting! Your rewards have been added to your bank.");
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        performer.getCommunicator().sendAlertServerMessage("Failed to add reward. Please submit a support ticket.");
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

private static SSLSocketFactory createTrustAllSocketFactory() throws IOException {
                try {
                    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                    TrustManager[] trustManagers = {
                            new X509TrustManager() {
                                @Override
                                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                                    /* empty */
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                                    /* empty */
                                }

                                @Override
                                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                                }
                            }
                    };
                    ctx.init(null, trustManagers, null);
                    return ctx.getSocketFactory();
                } catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
                    throw new IOException(ex);
                }
            }
```

The expectation is that when the command is issued in-game, the server will call the external site with the player's steam ID and generate either a 0 or 1 based on if they have voted.

Actual is getting a bad response code.

Comment: I hope that key you put in there isn't supposed to be secret. If it is, you need to change it *now*. Also, you're throwing an IOException on any status other than 200, but you're not reporting what the status is. I'd suggest logging the status code (and potentially the response body) so you can determine what the problem with your request is.

Comment: @ChrisThompson Yeah I reset the API key before posting. After taking your recommendation, looks like the code is coming back as 403, but in browser it comes up fine.

Comment: Actually that was all I needed. It was returning 403 because it needed a user-agent. Thank you man.